# How can I change the checkboxlist to look similar to on/off switch?

Tags: yii, yii2

Is there any way to change the checkboxlist widget to look similar to the on/off switch presented in Kartik's Switch Input Widget, but in a group?

I'm using this code:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'blocked_list')->checkboxList($array_list);
```

Which is very simple to use, but produces "simple" list...

I've tried with Karitk's like this:

```
foreach ($array_list as $category_id=>$category_name) {
    echo '<label class="control-label">' . $category_name . '</label>';
    echo SwitchInput::widget([
        'name'=>'blocked_list',
        'value'=>in_array($category_id, $model->blocked_list),
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'size' => 'mini',
        ],
    ]);
```

But it does not link with the model, and the Form looses it format

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 0):

I've got it!

```
    foreach ($category_array as $category_id=>$category_name) {
        if ( isset($model->blocked_list[$category_id]) )
            $model->blocked_list[$category_id] = true;
        else
            $model->blocked_list[$category_id] = false;

        echo $form->field($model, 'blocked_list[' . $category_id . ']')
            ->label($category_name)
            ->widget(SwitchInput::classname(), []);
}
```

I just added a validate "if" to ask if the variable to display exists, and then set the correct value for the model

Hope it helps someone